# Problem in Linear Transformations Involving Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am having troubles trying to solve the following problem:

**In R^3 we consider the subspaces S'={x,y,z ϵ R^3: x - y + z=0} and T= <(0,3,2>).
Now, we need to build a linear transformation f:R^3 → R^3 that satifies the following conditions:
f(S') belong to T, f(T) belong to S', and f (1,5,3) = (1,5,3).**

Therefore, what I thought that I could do, is to obtain a basis P formed by the characteristic eigenvectors of S' and T.
For that, I have assumed that an eigenvalue of S is 2, and eigenvectors are found by finding the basis for S', which is (1,1,0), (-1,0,1).
Furthermore, I also found, by the thrid condition given, that an eigenvalue is 1 and its corresponding eigenvector is also (1 5 3).

Having pointed that out, I just perfomed a matrix multiplication to obtain the matrix A, which will represent f in the cannonical basis. A=P^1DP.
I have also tried to find a vector which is a linear combination of the vectors of S' with respect to T, but I have failed.

However, I do not know if that method is good enough, can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: The question does not make sense.  What is $S$?  You define $S'$ as a subspace, you never define $S$. You also talk about the undefined $S$ as being a subspace, but then it does not make sense to talk about "eigenvectors of $S$" (eigenvectors are for linear transformations, not for subspaces).   Also, what exactly is the subspace $T$?  Is it the span of a single vector?

Comment: Yeah I am sorry, I am F(S`) was what I was referring to. Yeah, the subspace of T is given by a single vector, so we can deduce that a basis for T is (0,3,2).

Comment: Hello: typing all caps in polite company has been considered rude on the internet for at least a quarter century. Please don't do it.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: It is not possible for a subspace to consist of a single vector when that vector is nonzero. All subspaces include the zero vector, and all subspaces that contain at least 2 vectors must have an infinite number of vectors. What is the meaning of the inner product symbols around a vector: $T= <(0,3,2>$?

Comment: Maybe I approached wrong to the subspace T, and the vector given is a span of a single vector. I am really not sure.